# Proof of this property of greatest common divisor: $\gcd( n! + 1 , (n+1)! + 1 ) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, gcd-and-lcm

> Show that for any strictly positive integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ , one has
>   $\gcd( n! + 1 , (n+1)! + 1 ) = 1$

The hint given to me was :
Recall that the greatest commond divisor of any two integers $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ is defined as the unique
non-negative integer $gcd(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that
$\{ ar + bs \in \mathbb{Z} | r, s \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \gcd(a, b) · \mathbb{Z}$

I don't understand the equation $\{ ar + bs \in \mathbb{Z} | r, s \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \gcd(a, b) · \mathbb{Z}$.

help?

Comment: Hint:  if $p$ divides $a$ and $b$ then it divides $a-b$

Answer (score 1):

The hint that you were given basically amounts to [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity): for any integers $a,b$ there are integers $x,y$ such that $\gcd(a,b) = ax + by$.

I would suggest a different approach to this problem.  One property of gcds is
$$
\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a + mb,b)
$$
for any integer $m$.  (For this and other properties, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Properties).)  We can use this property to substract multiples of $b$ from $a$ in order to get a $\gcd$ of smaller, simpler numbers.

In your example, first note that $(n+1)(n! + 1) = (n+1)! + n + 1$ and
$$
(n+1)! + 1 - (n+1)(n! + 1) = (n+1)! + 1 - ((n+1)! + n + 1) = -n \, .
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\gcd( n! + 1 , (n+1)! + 1 ) &= \gcd(n! + 1, (n+1)! + 1 - (n+1)(n! + 1))\\
&= \gcd(n! + 1, -n) = \gcd(n! + 1, n) \, .
\end{align*}
You can see already that this expression is much simpler than the one we started with.  Do you see how to finish the computation?  What multiple of $n$ should I subtract from $n! + 1$ in order to conclude that the answer is $1$?

Comment: thank you very much for all your help!:)